# SQL Migration Plan

Tags: migration, backup

My employer is going to buy a new production box with enhanced memory/hardware capabilities.I have to move the existing production sql instance to the new environment with minimal downtime.

Since I have little experience as a DBA I am asking this generic question to the community.

Current Scenario:

1. Existing Production server is at a separate location.
2. New production box needs to be set up with same configuration as the existing one.(moving all users/security etc)
3. Move all database to the new box.(Current plan is to backup and compress to an External HD and do restore in the new sql installation)
   As of now all the db's after compression is less than 5GB.
4. Checks to perform at new Box after migration.
   Someone with great experience can do the step 2 and 4 easily.

Some questions like this are generic and need to understand the process step by step to perform the task.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The plan looks fine so far

Comment: I don't have a detailed plan/checklist to perform this task.An experienced DBA surely knows what to do exactly at each step.For me to set up the prod box which is of same config as the current one ,i assume there are lots of things to do other than just sql server installation.I expect those kind of information,It is more of a "things to do" while setting up the prod box.I guess it will helpful to all newbies who are struggling.

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but if there is noone with appropriate knowledge in your company, this is nothing to be solved with a checklist. There are many points to go wrong, many variables for each individual setup. Your company should look out for an experienced DBA to book for that task. Otherwise, if you have the new hardware at hand, there is nothing wrong in try and error

Comment: @NicoHaase : I understand your point.There should be an experienced DBA for doing this activity. Since i am assigned this task and i wanted to gain that experience ,i have posted this here to do the task properly.It is a great opportunity of learning for me.

Comment: You're welcome, and it's honorable that you try to learn from this task.